# I have to run the model many times

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I have the traffic simulation assignment 
I have to run the model many times using different arguments
I used behaviour space but it doesn't change the repetition or the number of the car and it never stopped

Comment: Show us your BehaviorSpace set up. You need to tell it when to stop (how do you stop it normally)? Also, BehaviorSpace can only change the values of variables that are on the interface (like sliders), not ones you set within the code.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is very common and almost always because you still have statements in your setup procedure that set the same variables you are using in BehaviorSpace. Remember that "setup" runs *after* BehaviorSpace changes the variables, so setup over-writes whatever BehaviorSpace does. Just comment out the "set ..." statements in setup that control the same variables as BehaviorSpace.